# Can I boot a LUKS encrypted system without editing /etc/crypttab and rebuilding the initramfs in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, lvm, luks

I am trying to boot an encrypted Ubuntu system without needing to have a custom initramfs for each disk I boot.  I currently use Funtoo/Gentoo and have a generic initramfs in which I specify the UUID at boot time which lets me have the same image across all devices with only a modified kernel cmdline.

I believe I must edit /etc/crypttab and then rebuild the initramfs; however, if I do that, then I have a USB stick that only works with the system it was generated.

Are there some other hidden options that I'm not seeing?

I also tried this on the kernel cmdline:
cryptopts=source=/dev/disk/by-uuid/ root=/dev//

However, that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If all the information that goes into `/etc/crypttab` that can vary between your target disks is supplied in the kernel command line, how about writing a script that reads the kernel command line from `/proc/cmdline` and edits `/etc/crypttab` for you?

Then you could place the script into initramfs - or rather, into `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/<appropriate directory>` so it gets picked up by `update-initramfs` whenever a new initramfs is created.

This way, you could have a custom generic initramfs that can accept any encrypted system disk.

Comment: I think that is the likely solution, I was hoping with Ubuntu, that would already be standard so I wouldn't need a custom solution - I'll give that a try, but am hoping that I'm missing some option that would simplify this solution.